# Yii Scope not returning desired columns

Tags: php, yii

In my `Ads` model, i have a scope, that creates a join to another table

```
public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'GetCustom'=> array(
                    'alias' => 't',
                    'select'=> 't.*, t2.make, COUNT(t2.id) AS Count',
                    'join' => 'JOIN `make` AS t2',
                    'condition'=>'t.make_id=t2.id AND t.pending!=1',
                    'group'=>'t2.make',
                    'order'=>'Count DESC',
                    'limit'=>'24'

            ),
        );
    }

public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            '_make' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Make', 'make_id')        
        );
    }
```

then in my `$dataprovider`

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Ads::model()->GetCustom(), array(
                        'pagination'=>false, //disable pagination
                    ));
```

the scope generates the correct query

```
SELECT t.*,t2.make, COUNT(t2.id) AS Count FROM `ads`
`t` JOIN `make` AS t2 WHERE t.make_id=t2.id AND t.pending!=1 GROUP
BY t2.make ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 24
```

but in my `view` i can only get ALL columns in the `t.*` table. i get a not defined error when trying to calling objects in the t2 table.

What am i doing wrong here? Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
in my view:

```
 $a = Ads::model()->GetCustom()->findAll();
    print_r($a);
```

code above, gives me this array. It returns 24 array locations, but i only included 1.

```
Array ( [0] => Ads Object ( [state_name] => [contact_method] => [file] => [mime_type] => [size] => [name] => [filename] => [secureFileNames] => [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( **[ALL COLUMNS IN TABLE ADS ONLY!!!]** ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 1 [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

Comment: Please show what `$a = Ads::model->GetCustom()->findAll(); var_dump($a);` prints out

Comment: did you try yo use defaultScope?

Comment: @user2883814 i want the option to call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the columns of t2 table are not an attributes of Ads model.
To overcome that you have to simply add a property of ads model.

In your case your query should be

```
SELECT t.*,**t2.make as t2_make**, COUNT(t2.id) AS Count FROM `ads`
`t` JOIN `make` AS t2 WHERE t.make_id=t2.id AND t.pending!=1 GROUP
BY t2.make ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 24 .
```

And add property to your ads model

```
public $t2_make;
```

Then you can access it at your view like `$model->t2_make;` and `$data->t2_make` at your gridview.